# Importing MS Project 2013 data into Oracle 11g database

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g, odbc, ms-project

Does anyone know if there is a straightforward way to get data out of MS Project 2013 and into Oracle 11g?  We have a master schedule created in MS Proj and want to create a web-based application that will perform monitoring and metrics charting of the project schedule statuses.  I have successfully exported to CSV and imported into Oracle, but this was cumbersome and required a lot of formatting of the data in the CSV format before it was pushed back into Oracle.  I'm in the beginning phases here, but wanted to solicit anyone who may have had experience with this in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind writing a little code, you could use [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net). You should be able to extract what you need using Java or a .Net language. You can perform the import directly in code, or just generate a suitably formatted output file for import into Oracle using other tools.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I vaguely remember coming across MPXJ while looking into Apache POI a while back, so thanks for bringing it back to my attention. I don't mind writing some code, although I'm not real familiar with Java. Gotta start somewhere, so let my Java programming experience begin. Thanks again.